# Unit Testing Classes VS Methods

Tags: unit-testing, junit

When unit testing, is it better practice to test a class or individual methods?

Most of the examples I've seen, test the class apart from other classes, mocking dependencies between classes. Another method I've played around w/ is mocking methods you're not testing (by overriding) so that you're only testing the code in one method. Thus 1 bug breaks 1 test since the methods are isolated from each other.

I was wondering if there is a standard method and if there are any big disadvantages to isolating each method for testing as opposed to isolating classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *unit testing* comes from hardware systems testing, and is more or less semantics-free when applied to software. It can get used for anything from isolation testing of a single routine to testing a complete system in headless mode with an in-memory database.

So don't trust anyone who argues that the definition implies there is only one way to do things independently of context; there a variety of ways, some of which are sometimes more useful than others. And presumably every approach a smart person would argue for has at least some value somewhere.

The smallest unit of hardware is the atom, or perhaps some subatomic particle. Some people test software like they were scanning each atom to see if the laws of quantum mechanics still held. Others take a battleship and [see if it floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasa_%28ship%29).

Something in between is very likely better. Once you know something about the kind of thing you are producing beyond 'it is software', you can start to come up with a plan that is appropriate to what you are supposed to be doing.

Comment: Great answer. I know it's up to the developer to decide what "unit" he's testing, I just didn't know if there were head-sized holes in walls next to monitors that I could learn a lesson from. Based on these answers and especially yours, it looks like it's just what makes most sense for the problem and the developer and there's not necessarily a "better" approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no one standard answer. Unit tests are for the developer (or they should be), do what is most helpful to you.

One downside of testing individual methods is you may not test the actual behavior of the object. If the mocking of some methods is not accurate that may go undetected. Also mocks are a lot of work, and they tend to make the tests very fragile, because they make the tests care a lot about what specific method calls take place.

In my own code I try whenever possible to separate infrastructure-type dependencies from business logic so that I can write tests of the business logic classes entirely without mocks. If you have a nasty legacy code base it probably makes more sense to test individual methods and mock any collaborating methods of the object, in order to insulate the parts from each other.

Theoretically objects are supposed to be cohesive so it would make sense to test them as a whole. In practice a lot of things are not particularly object-oriented. In some cases it is easier to mock collaborator methods than it is to mock injected dependencies that get called by the collaborators.

Answer (score 0):

The point of unit testing is to test a unit of code i.e. class.

This gives you confidence that part of the code on its one is doing what is expected.

This is also the first part of the testing process. It helps to catch those pesky bugs as early as possible and having a unit test to demonstrate it makes it easier to fix that further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing by definition is testing the smallest piece of written code you can. "Units" are not classes they are methods.

Every public method should have at least 1 unit test, that tests that method specifically.

If you follow the rule above, you will eventually get to where class interactions are being covered. As long as you write 1 test per method, you will cover class interaction as well.